# What to use to tame my chicken tikka masala?

Tags: chicken, flavor

I love chicken Tikka Masala but I’m afraid it doesn’t always like me.  If I cut the masala portion in half what can I use in its place? Maybe double the yogurt?

Note: The dinner is a meal kit with the masala sauce provided in a sealed packet.  The sauce is in liquid form, not a powder.  The amount of sauce is meant to go with 1/2 lb of chicken thigh meat.  The meal kit is meant to serve two.

Comment: Another though about these kits - is it just a sauce packet, or is there a dry seasoning packet as well - I haven't done a tikka masala that way but I have had others like it.   In that case a lot of the heat may be in the dry mix.

Comment: Is your problem with spices on the way in or the way out?

Comment: @user3067860 The spices are causing issues such as indigestion and heartburn.

Comment: @ChrisH The sauce is in an ‘all-in-one’ packet, in liquid form.  There is no dry seasoning packet in this kit.

Comment: I would just put some yoghurt on the side, as a dip.

Comment: Are you able to tolerate other foods with lactose in them? If you're having digestive issues due to lactose intolerance, adding more yoghurt will probably just make things worse!

Comment: @nick012000 I have no sensitivity to lactose but thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: it could also be the acid. Some of the spices are acidic, tomatoes are acidic, and yogurt is acidic.  I dare say you could add a pinch of baking soda

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines with using yoghurt. In fact because yoghurt is often used to tone down spice, you might find that you can use more than half the sauce, if you increase the yoghurt.

But you probably wouldn't want to double the yoghurt to make up for the missing sauce. Instead replace the sauce you didn't use with yoghurt. So if the packet contains 200 ml  of sauce, and you only use half of it, you'll be short 100 ml, so use an extra 100ml yoghurt. You might find that's a little runny, so might want to use a bit less.

If you have tomato puree/paste or even passata, you could mix some of that into the extra yoghurt. Most tikka masala recipes include some tomato, so this will maintain the flavour without the heat. Puree will have a slight thickening effect compared to yoghurt, while passata will be thinner,unless you simmer it long enough to reduce.

Comment: Are you suggesting adding (maybe) tomato sauce or tomato paste to keep the sauce thick and tone down the ‘temperature’ while adding more yogurt?  I like that idea!

Comment: @tale852150 not tomato sauce, but tomato paste. It will help with the thickness to some extent, but also I reckon you want to reduce heat without reducing too much flavour, and it will help there, by replacing some of the original overly-hot sauce.  If there was an easy way of adding onion, that would be good too, but I can't think of one

Comment: I will try the tomato paste then.  I’m curious - where in the spice-heat spectrum does masala usually fall? Is it in the ‘hot’ side of the spectrum or more so on the ‘mild’ side?

Comment: It's rather variable. It should (IMO) be noticeably hot but less than madras. But this is a UK-based opinion, and anyway perception of heat is very personal

Comment: Understood - my understanding is like yours in that in can vary but is usually on the ‘hot’ side versus the ‘mild’ side.  What would you suggest as a ‘mild’ alternative - possibly a curry like Korma?

Comment: To me, korma has no heat (my daughter would agree and she doesn't do "spicy").  It's pleasant enough but a different experience. Pasanda is similar in heat but IMO often better in restaurants. Tikka masala is normally described as "medium", along with dhansak, which I'd choose in preference as I like its sweet and sour notes if I don't feel like something really spicy.  A toned down tikka masala isn't  a bad idea.  If you start from scratch or building a sauce using a ready-made paste and fresh ingredients you can reduce just the spices to taste.  It is of course more work.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure that yoghurt helps with the problems the OP asked about. Yes, it will make the spices less aggressive in the mouth, but it won't remove any of the capsaicin, so after the stomach it'll probably behave the same whether or not any yoghurt was in the food. In that sense the yoghurt might actually give a treacherous sense of safety. – However, @tale852150 you should also consider that it's maybe not the spices at all that are causing the digestion problems. It's generally difficult to diagnose what food item caused such problems, since the effects can have quite a delay.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, I see your point. But how else to start, how else to diagnose the culprit?  It may simply be that I cannot tolerate some other spice within the masala.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the yoghurt is mainly there to replace the missing volume/liquid caused by putting less of the spicy sauce in - and that will reduce the capsaicin and any other irritating spices.  If it's an issue of heat in the mouth, there's perhaps more room for balancing yoghurt vs spice than if it's digestive.

Comment: @ChrisH The issue is with the digestive part - my mouth has no issues and in fact loves it. :-)

Comment: Does adding 1/2 tablespoon of ground cumin increase, decrease or makes little difference with regard to indigestion?

Comment: That's what I was starting to assume - still, reducing the spicy sauce and building the volume back up with other suitable thick liquids is the way to go.  It becomes a matter of personal experimentation, but anecdotally your choice of accompanying drink can have an effect too